# Android - Como chamar um método de outra class a partir do onCreate()?

Tags: java, android

Eu sou bem novo em Android. Então se puder explicar a lógica por trás do problema eu agradeceria. Isso me ajudaria a entender o problema e ver como eu poderia resolve-lo se acontece-se de novo.

Na activity um eu tenho um método que é executado quando um certo botão é clicado. O mesmo botão está na outra activity, então, em vez de criar o mesmo método duas vezes e dizer tudo que o que ele tem que fazer, eu gostaria apenas de chamar o método que está dentro da activity1. Isso a partir do onCreate();

Qualquer ajuda é válida!

Activity 1 (trecho)

```
//Do intent on Button shopButton
public void buttonIntent(){
    Button buttonShop = findViewById(R.id.shopButton);
    if (buttonShop != null){
        buttonShop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShopActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity 2

```
package com.example.android.musique;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        //Create an MainActivity Object
        MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();

        //Call methods what catches the button and do intent from MainActivity
        mainAct.buttonIntent();
    }

}
```

LOGCAT

```
01-10 22:24:16.514 8887-8956/com.example.android.musique D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738371
01-10 22:24:16.516 8887-8956/com.example.android.musique D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 240518168576
01-10 22:24:16.518 8887-8956/com.example.android.musique D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 68724719680
01-10 22:24:16.529 8887-8956/com.example.android.musique D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7a2b9b5780) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
01-10 22:24:16.539 8887-8887/com.example.android.musique V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#81810100
01-10 22:24:16.564 8887-8956/com.example.android.musique D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7a2b9b6200) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
01-10 22:24:17.401 8887-8894/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-10 22:24:17.829 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738369
01-10 22:24:18.383 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 7 upload: x, y, width height = 72, 18, 28, 103
01-10 22:24:18.392 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 7 upload: x, y, width height = 84, 120, 17, 90
01-10 22:24:18.408 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 7 upload: x, y, width height = 84, 209, 15, 24
01-10 22:24:18.507 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103079215104
01-10 22:24:19.352 8887-8956/? D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103084458052
01-10 22:24:24.085 8887-8887/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-10 22:24:24.095 8887-8887/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.android.musique, PID: 8887
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.musique/com.example.android.musique.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2810)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6275)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                     at com.example.android.musique.MainActivity.buttonIntent(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                     at com.example.android.musique.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:19)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6717)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2698)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2810) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6275) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menos que esse método seja `static` ou você crie uma classe da qual suas `activity` derivem, você precisara implementar esse método em ambas.

O erro do seu log é derivado do fato que você tentou instanciar a `activity` manualmente com `MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();`

O Android não vai simplesmente criar um objeto da activity, ele tentara "colocar para rodar" ela.

Mudar seu método para estático deve resolver seu problema.

```
public static void buttonIntent(final Activity activity){
    Button buttonShop = activity.findViewById(R.id.shopButton);
    if (buttonShop != null){
        buttonShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, ShopActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainActivity asd = new MainActivity();
asd.buttonIntent();`

buttonIntent (Activity) in MainActivity cannot be applied. 

Fico preso nesse resultado

Comment: Você utilizara assim: `MainActivity.buttonIntent(this);` onde `this` é a referencia da Activity onde o método foi chamado. Você não precisa instanciar um novo objeto.